# Does Quarkus (panache) support SAP HANA db access?

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, hana, quarkus-panache

I plan to build a platform which i want to use Quarkus for (for the first time, coming from Spring Boot). The platform will use PostgreSQL as persistent storages, however there may be cases where a microservices has to connect to SAP HANA storages to read data from. I know there are java drivers for SAP HANA, but does Quarkus cause issues with this or is there some kind of "lack" of integration for this when for example using the panache module from Quarkus? I don't think i saw it on the list of supported databases. I only found one example on github of someone claiming using sap hana integration, but it was just a private person nothing official. Does anyone know or has done that and seen whether this causes issues in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Since Hibernate supports SAP HANA, Quarkus does so as well in JVM mode at least. If you want support for native image, you will have to contact SAP so that they make sure their JDBC driver works in native mode.